# My login script with username, password and PIN code, doesn't login with pin (Somehow)

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

I got a small issue...
I have my own website with a simple mysqli login script, that logs me on, whenever I type in my username, password and PIN code...

My problem is now, that I can login to my site using only username and password (without entering a PIN code...), but whenever I type in a PIN code, it has to be the right pin...

What can I do to solve this problem?

My code:

```html
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");  
 session_start();  
 if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))  
 {  
      header("location:entry.php");  
 }  
 
 if(isset($_POST["login"]))  
 {  
      if(empty($_POST["username"]) && empty($_POST["pin"]))  
      {  
           echo '<script>alert("Alle felter SKAL udfyldes!")</script>';  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["username"]);  
           $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["password"]);  
           $pin = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["pin"]);  
           $password = sha1($password);  
     $pin = sha1($pin);
           $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' AND pin = '$pin'";  
           $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
           if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
           {  
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
                header("location:entry.php");  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                echo '<script>alert("Forkert brugernavn, adgangskode eller pin-kode")</script>';  
           }  
      }  
 }  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
   <script>
   var loc = window.location.href+'';
if (loc.indexOf('http://')==0){
    window.location.href = loc.replace('http://','https://');
}
   </script>
           <title>
    MJVS - Private area.
     </title>  
     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/title_logo.png" />
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  

   </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                <h3 align="center"></h3>  
                <br /> 
                <h3 align="center"><b>Login</b></h3>  
                <br />  
                <form method="post">  
                     <label>Enter Username</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <label>Enter Password</label>  
                     <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
      <label>Enter PIN</label>  
                     <input type="password" name="pin" class="form-control" maxlength="4" />  
                     <br />  
                     <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-info" />  
                     <br />   
                </form>  
                <?php       
                
?>
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

Comment: you're going to have to do something like store the value of `$pin` in the database or cache it or something, once the value of `$pin` is generated, and then retrieve that value and compare it to the user's input to that value!

Comment: Check your database; it sounds like you have two sets of credentials for yourself, one with a PIN and one without.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code :-

```
 <?php  
   $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");  
   session_start();  
   if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))  
   {  
       header("location:entry.php");  
   }  

   if(isset($_POST["login"]))  
   {  
       if($_POST["username"] == '' || $_POST["pin"] == '')  
       {  
            echo '<script>alert("Alle felter SKAL udfyldes!")</script>';  
       }  
       else  
       {  
           $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["username"]);  
           $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["password"]);  
           $pin = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["pin"]);  
           $password = sha1($password);  
           $pin = sha1($pin);
           $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";  
           $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
           if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
           {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($connect, $result) ;
                $pass = $row['password'] ;
                $check_pin = $row['pin'] ;

                if ($password === $pass && $pin === $check_pin){
                   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
                   header("location:entry.php");
                }    
           }  
           else  
           {  
                echo '<script>alert("Forkert brugernavn, adgangskode eller pin-kode")</script>';  
           }  
      }  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: The PIN is a self-chosen PIN code, just for secure bruteforcing... Whenever I use your code, I'm unable to sign in. IDK what it could be...

Comment: Can you please share your user table ?

Comment: At the time of registration , do you use sha1() or something more to sha1() ?

Comment: Use $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($connect, $result)

Comment: Use the above code again and let me know if you get any error .

Comment: #2 - Yes, of course! My VPN is turned off right now, and I'm on work, so that'll be a little later! - 

#3 - I encrypt with sha1 both Password and PIN. - 

#4 + #5 - I will do that in some hours! Thanks :)

Comment: I'm getting the following error: "
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in D:\- FTP\- WEB\- WEB 5.0\index.php on line 26"

Comment: Please use mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)

Comment: I would, if I knew how to... I’m sorry, I’m no programmer, and I’ve googled for hours now... Guess programming just isn’t for me, hm... Can you tell me a specified location whereto I should write what?:/

Comment: Use one parameter in mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: That simply doesn't work. It won't let me log in, nor will it with your code